# CompletableFuture thenAccept does not work

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

Welcome,
I am so confused why this part of code does not work.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    final String URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1";

    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(new URI(URL)).GET().timeout(Duration.of(10, ChronoUnit.SECONDS)).build();

    HttpClient.newHttpClient().sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()).thenAcceptAsync(r -> {
        System.out.println(r.statusCode());
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));

    
    System.out.println("END OF PROGRAM");
}
```

}

And the result is:

```
END OF PROGRAM
```

If i have provided ExecutorService JVM should wait for CompletableFuture was completed (.thenAceptAsync section) but the program was finishing immediately.

Probably my mindset is wrong. Could somebody explain me this?

Comment: You don’t wait for the request to finish; your program just exits.

Comment: How should i make it correct?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join()

Comment: Soo i have to join it to MainThread. I thank earlier that JVM works as long as any thread exists. I was wrong thanks a lot

Comment: You `sendAsync` without specifying an executor; so the common pool is used. I don’t think your code will get as far as using your custom executor.

Answer (score 1):

The program exits before the request is completed. The request is executed asynchronously using `sendAsync` and therefore it does not block the execution of the program.

To block the execution and wait for the API response, you must use `response.get();` as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, ExecutionException,
     InterruptedException {
final String URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1";
    
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(new URI(URL)).GET().timeout(Duration.of(10, ChronoUnit.SECONDS)).build();
    
CompletableFuture<Void> response = HttpClient.newHttpClient()
                    .sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                    .thenAcceptAsync(r -> {
                System.out.println(r.statusCode());
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
}, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
    
 response.get();//wait for API response
 System.out.println("END OF PROGRAM");
}
```

Output:

```
200
pool-1-thread-1
END OF PROGRAM
```